# scheduling a job to download files from ftp

Tags: linux, debian, scheduled-tasks

I see there're so many threads regarding job scheduling and it seems it takes me long time to find out which one is what I'm looking for.
So let me describe what I need, and if there are related thread I'd be grateful if you point me one.

I'm planning to create a scheduled task on a debian machine, to run every, let's say, 15 mins to download files from ftp server to some local folder.

What's tools/programs will I need for this?

I think I will need to use some programming language to code a logic for downloading files, so the issue how to make this program run as a scheduled task.

Please edit my thread if you find it's not good expressed.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [cron](http://www.pantz.org/software/cron/croninfo.html)
edit your `/etc/crontab` to :

```
*/15 * * * * /path/to/file
```

in `/path/to/file` write your [ftp command](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-ftp-commands/):

```
ftp google.com
```

Comment: let me clarify. If program is called "download.py", do you mean I will substitute "file" with download.py ?

Comment: yes so `*/15 * * * * /home/Askar/download.py` assuming it is in your home directory